# Optimised function layout

Tags: php, function

I am trying to figure out which will be the most optimized way to layout my function.

The function has three variables, 2 of which are required.

Currently, I am using conditionals to first check the `round_id`, then inside the `round_id` conditional, I check what `type`, then inside that if a `category_id` exists (which is optional).

Does this look to be the best way to run as little conditions as possible?

```
 function count() {

    var type = *post*; // Required
    var category_id = *post*; // Optional
    var round_id = *post*; // Required

    if ( round_id == "pre" ) {

        if ( type == "adult" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        } elseif ( type == "youth" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        }

    } elseif ( round_id == "1" ) {

        if ( type == "adult" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        } elseif ( type == "youth" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        }

    } elseif ( round_id == "2" ) {

        if ( type == "adult" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        } elseif ( type == "youth" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        }

    } elseif ( round_id == "3" ) {

        if ( type == "adult" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        } elseif ( type == "youth" ) {

            if ( category_id ) {

            } else {

            }

        }

    } else {

        Error

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey i will delete this comment soon but i have the answer for the post you have deleted 5 min ago : 
[PHPDEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9020c133731408e8a615abbab506f31dfdd7fc61)

The problem seem to be your public declaration